# How to list down all filenames contains space and started with number with for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

All files with `ls -1`

```
wolf@linux:~$ ls -1
'1 file.txt'
'2 file.txt'
'3 file.txt'
'abc def.txt'
wolf@linux:~$
```

All files with `for loop`

```
wolf@linux:~$ for f in *; do echo $f; done
1 file.txt
2 file.txt
3 file.txt
abc def.txt
wolf@linux:~$
```

View filenames started with number

```
wolf@linux:~$ ls | grep ^[0-9]
1 file.txt
2 file.txt
3 file.txt
wolf@linux:~$
```

When I replace `*` with `ls | grep ^[0-9]` in the for loop

```
for f in `ls | grep ^[0-9]`; do echo $f; done
```

or

```
for f in $(ls | grep ^[0-9]); do echo $f; done
```

I'm getting this output

```
wolf@linux:~$ for f in $(ls | grep ^[0-9]); do echo $f; done
1
file.txt
2
file.txt
3
file.txt
wolf@linux:~$
```

May I know why? I would like to get output like this with `for loop`

**Update 1**

```
wolf@linux:~$ SAVEIFS=$IFS; for f in `ls | grep "^[0-9].*\s"`; do echo "$f"; done; IFS=$SAVEIFS
01
file.txt
02
file.txt
03
file.txt
wolf@linux:~$
```

**Update 2**

```
wolf@linux:~$ for f in $(ls -1 [[:digit:]]*); do echo "$f"; done 
01
file.txt
02
file.txt
03
file.txt
wolf@linux:~$
```

**Desired Ouutput** - file started with numbers only using for loop

```
1 file.txt
2 file.txt
3 file.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> May I know why? I would like to get output like this with for loop

The syntax

```
$(ls ...)
```

Is subject to word splitting. see [Word Splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and the common pitfall, [Bash Pitfall](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Test the beginning of the word, if it starts with a digit and if it has spaces, something like.

```sh
for f in *.txt; do [[ $f == [0-9]* && $f == *\ * ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

without the test, you can match the files directly, something like.

```sh
for f in [0-9]*\ *.txt; do echo "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `printf` instead of a `for` loop and `ls`:

```
printf '%s\n' [0-9]*\ *
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' [0-9]*" "*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ls | grep "^[0-9].*\s"`. That'll get you files starting with a number and contains a space.

**Test case**

```
$> ls -1
1 file.txt
2 file.txt
3 file.txt
abc def.txt
testing.txt
```

**Result**

```
$> ls | grep "^[0-9].*\s"
1 file.txt
2 file.txt
3 file.txt
```

**For loop**

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS='\n'; for f in `ls | grep "^[0-9].*\s"`; do echo "$f"; done; IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

**Simple bash script**

```
#!/bin/bash

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS='\n'
for f in `ls | grep "^[0-9].*\s"`;
do
    echo "$f"
done;

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

**Explanation**

There's a variable called IFS which means internal field separator. By default it is set to space. So, file name with space splits into different lines. If you reset the IFS variable to say, `\n`, your file name with space will print fine. You can then reset IFS back again after you are done.

Comment: Thanks @zedfoxus, however the for loop produces exactly same output as mine

Comment: I have in my answer at the bottom two different statements. One starting with `SAVEIFS` and the other is a bash script. Try them out and see. I tested it and their output looks just like you desire.

Comment: Thanks. `Simple bash script` works. But `For loop` don't. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Wolf My comment isn't typing right due to backticks. Copy and paste the script under `For loop` in my answer and see how that works for you.

Comment: Superb. Both code works now. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The glob-pattern for filenames which start with a digit and contain a space, is `[0-9]*' '*`.

If you need to process the list in your script, consider assigning them to an array:

```
list_of_filenames=( [0-9]*' '* )
```

or in a loop, as you originally requested:

```
for name in [0-9]*' '*
do
  if [[ -f $name ]] # Makes sure it is really a file!
  then
    ....
  fi
done
```